# How to display first 6 records visible and remaining record should disable in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 100 records in my table and I have to display all records but visible first 6 records and disable remain records.

I tried query

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE p_type=1 Order By date_of_add_product ASC LIMIT 6
```

It will display first 6 records but I need to display remaining all records and that should be disabled. Would you help me out with logic in this?

Comment: Can you please post your code for the logic that you tried?

Comment: How do you want to disable? Grayed out or non-clickable or something else?

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.manian, Actually I don't understand the logic from where I have to start. I am able to fetch the records from database

Comment: grayed or non-clickable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below code,

```
$i = 0;
$query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE p_type=1 Order By date_of_add_product ASC";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

while($row = $result->fetch_array()) { 
  if($i<6) { ?>
     <a href="product.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" ><?php echo $row['product_name']; ?></a>
  <?php } else { ?>
     <a href="JavaScript:void(0);" class="disabled"><?php echo $row['product_name']; ?></a>
  <?php }
  $i++;
}
```

Add this css too,

```
a { color: red; }
a.disabled { color: gray; }
```

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.manian, It's working for me.Thanks for your help. Upvote from my side